# Configure related list in compact layout (hover)

Tags: lightning, compact-layout

I want to manage the related list visualised in the compact layout hover that appears when I put the mouse cursor over a lookup field.

[image: Compact layout hover on account lookup]

For example I want to configure which related lists to display for the account lookup field on contact object or remove them altogether.
Anyone know how this configuration can be done?

Comment: From what I have found, this is a feature reserved for certain standard objects and is not something you can configure for yourself.